# Jmeter plugins manager failed to install plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

JMeter (version 4.0) plugins manager (jmeter-plugins-manager-1.0.2) failed to install plugins.

Following error is thrown.

```
2018-05-29 12:39:00,977 ERROR o.j.r.PluginManager: Failed to download cmdrunner>=2.2
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJAR(JARSourceHTTP.java:395) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.applyChanges(PluginManager.java:167) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerDialog$4.run(PluginManagerDialog.java:226) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.0.2.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick fix: 
download jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/cmdrunner/2.2.1
and place it int jmeter/library folder